# Im trying to scan my wifi network to find out when my phone connects, where am i going wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, subprocess

I am running python 3.7 on macOS

I am trying to have my code scan my wifi network to see when my phone joins the specified wifi network, i provide the routers ip address ("ip") and the phones assigned ip address when it connects to that specified wifi ("device")

When i run my code i get no errors but i also get no output

I have tried using "subprocess.Popen(["say, 'Iphone just connected to the network'"]) to speak but that did not work so i tried echo and say, which also did not work.
At this point i'm not sure what part of my code is the part that is not working, this is my first try at automation so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

```
import sys
import subprocess 
import os
from decouple import config


ip = "192.168.*.***"
device = "192.168.*.***"

proc = subprocess.Popen(["ping", ip],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
  line = proc.stdout.readline()
  if not line:
    break
  
  connected_ip = line.decode('utf-8').split()[3]

  if connected_ip == device:
    os.system("echo 'Iphone just connected to the network'")
    os.system("say 'Iphone just connected to the network'")
      
      
'''subprocess.Popen(["say, 'Iphone just connected to the network'"])'''
```

Comment: I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.